# Bootstrap v4.3 Navbar not animating the show transition of collapsed non-navbar element correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a modified pills menu system that displays a collapsed structure on small screens and mobile devices. The issue that I am having is that when the 'menu' button is pressed the pill items do not show with a transitional effect has I would expected if they were part of the navigation bar, instead it takes approximately half a second to appear which is not ideal. I assume that the transition works in a relative fashion to the navbar and therefore one would need to slightly alter the method for it to reveal manual hidden elements like I have in my example below:

```css
.xs-collapse {
  display: none;
  
}

body {
    background-color: aqua;
}



@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .xs-toggle {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .xs-collapse {
    display: block;
     
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <title>Hello, wasasorld!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Container start -->
      <div class="row">
        
        <!-- row start -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">

          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light  xs-toggle">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                  <img src="./images/logo.svg" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">

              </a>
              <button  class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#v-pills-tab" aria-controls="v-pills-tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
          </nav>
           

            <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills xs-collapse collapse" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                <li><a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
              </div>
        </div>


         
            
            <!-- row end -->
      </div>

    

      <!-- Container end -->
    </div>

    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see the the menu item does not work correctly and any help to resolve this issue would be most appreciated.

many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only posted the relevant code for you. This will give you a hint into the right direction.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</nav>
<div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
        <h4 class="text-white">Collapsed content</h4>
        <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <li><a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[here is fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/mattopen/sy9x1bck/)

Comment: @W9914420 do you need more information? then please drop me a note.

Comment: this is much appreciated I used the wrong approached before this is much better solution. Thank you :)